# Querying repeated key value fields in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

<s>maybe i don't get the obvious but i do not get the right query for this.</s>

I have multiple key value pairs (repeated data) per data row, for example:
{"row1":"data1","row2":"data2","row3":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},"row4":{"key1A":"value1A","key2A":"value2A"}}

I try to get the "value1" for all records where in row3 "key1" is set. The same combined with row4, so if key2A is set, get me the corresponding value.

I hope i described my problem properly.

EDIT:
For better understanding, this is an example schema of one data-row:

`{
    "exrow":"Example Data",
    "date":"2017-08-07",
    "hi": [
        "cd":[
            {"index":1,"value":"car"},
            {"index":2,"value":"boat"},
            {"index":3,"value":"green"},
            {"index":4,"value":"blue"}
        ],
        [...]
    ],
    [...]
}`

thereby `'hi'` and `'cd'` is `RECORD, REPEATED`.

So what i try to get is the following result row:
`Example Data | 2017-08-07 | boat | blue`

The query - just for understanding - would be:

`SELECT
    exrow,
    date,
    (SELECT hi.cd.value WHERE hi.cd.index=2),
    (SELECT hi.cd.value WHERE hi.cd.index=4)
FROM
    table`

So i'm trying to query two repeated (nested?) data rows with an corresponding condition.

I hope i explained it better now.

Comment: not clear  - what is the schema of your table?

Comment: I edited my post and tried to explain it better

Comment: schema you provided is most likely incorrect as `Nested Arrays` are not supported by ARRAY type in BigQuery - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#declaring-an-array-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess, with the data provided:

```
#standardSQL
WITH table AS (
 SELECT [STRUCT('key1' AS key,2 AS value), ('key2', 3), ('key3', 8)] arr
)

SELECT (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(arr) WHERE key='key2') result
FROM `table`
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(arr) WHERE key='key3' AND value=8)
```

Comment: I do not quite understand it yet, therefore I edited my post and tried to explain it better.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem with an combination of Joins and FLATTEN. But your comment was the reason for me to get on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at below one :

```
SELECT
address.emailAddress, address.options.changeSource, address.options.type
from addresses.address
where address.options.type="main" or address.options.type="second"
group by address.emailAddress, address.options.changeSource, address.options.type
```

adress, emailAddress and options are repeated fields.

So first option how we can  deal with repeated fields is simply "group by".

Second option you can use is FLATTEN.

For more info I recommend big query reference - is very useful

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#flatten

Comment: Thanks, i managed to solve my problem with an combination of Joins and FLATTEN.